# How to iterate through GeoJson Feed for Google Map

Tags: javascript, geojson

So, I have a GeoJson Feed that looks like this

```
 {
  "type" : "FeatureCollection",
  "features" : [
    {
      "type" : "Feature",
      "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
          -84.50926612,
          39.1423275
        ]
      },
      "properties" : {
        "name" : "<a href=\"/Things-To-Do/Attractions/cincinnati-zoo-botanical-garden\">Cincinnati Zoo &amp; Botanical Garden</a>",
        "description" : ""
      }
    },
    {
      "type" : "Feature",
      "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
          -84.495935481675,
          39.095853705988
        ]
      },
      "properties" : {
        "name" : "<a href=\"/Things-To-Do/Attractions/bb-riverboats-thanksgiving-day-cruise\">BB Riverboats Thanksgiving Day Cruise</a>",
        "description" : ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am loading it with this function

```
var attbut = document.getElementById('loadatt');
attbut.addEventListener('click', function() {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'path-to-GeoJson', true);
xhr.onload = function() {
loadAttractions(this.responseText);
};
xhr.send();
});
```

And it is loading fine.  However I can't seem to get the 'length' property to iterate.

```
function loadAttractions(results) {
log(results.FeatureCollection.length);
for (var i = 0; i < results.FeatureCollection.length; i++) {
var coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1],coords[0]);
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: latLng,
     map: map
     });
}
}
```

I have tried `results.features.length`, and `results.FeatureCollection.features.length`, the only thing that "works" is `results.length`, which gives the whole array.  Everything else gives an undefined error.

Thanks for any suggestions or help.

Comment: Asumming your json object is assinged to a variabled called results. It is not an array it is an object. results.features.length should work fine

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I call it 'results' in the loadattractions function.  Ie, function 1, load the data and passes it to loadAtrractions(results).  Then trying to get the length of results. results.feaures.length DOES NOT work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who helped.  My problem was that I was fetching the JSON as 'text'

loadAttractions(this.responseText);

When I should have been parsing as JSON

var results = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

That made it work.  Thanks again to all.

Answer (score 1):

As Dalorzo mentions, if you have the results var, results.features.length works with that data for me.

If you have access to underscore.js, there is a method _.size that will give you the number of objects, but it does not appear that you'll need it to grab this.

Comment: But it doesn't.  I get Cannot read property 'length' of undefined when I use results.features.length -- only results.length works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle working with `results.features.length`.

http://jsfiddle.net/dXQeP/

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It is so strange.  I set the response.text to the variable results (I even alerted the results) so it deifintely is there. But I continue to get undefined error on length.